# Dynamic Menus Binding in mud blazor Navigation Menu component

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I'm trying to use a `foreach` loop in a `MudBlazor Nav` menu component.

```
<MudNavMenu>
        @{
            if (dtX != null && dtX.Rows.Count > 0)
            {               
                for (int i = 0; i < @dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Program_ID = Convert.ToInt32(@dt.Rows[i]["Program_ID"]);
                    Program_Icon2 = dt.Rows[i]["Program_Icon"].ToString();
                    <MudNavGroup  Title="@Program_Name">
                        @foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                        {
                            Program_ID_Level2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Program_ID"]);
                            Program_Name_Level2 = dr["Program_Name"].ToString();
                        }
                    </MudNavGroup>
                }
            }
        }
</MudNavMenu>
```

Running this doesn't throw any exceptions but it seems that `MudBlazor` components are unable to use looped elements. How else can I loop through them?

Comment: You might want to check documentation to see if there is another way to iterate through the data.

Comment: No, They don't have any documentation on dynamic binding

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `MudNavLink` that should be in `MudNavGroup`

Added minimal working example as asked:

```
<MudNavMenu>
        @if (_menuList != null && _menuList.Count > 0)
        {
            <MudNavGroup Title="Example">
                @foreach (var item in _menuList)
                {
                    <MudNavLink Href="@item">@item</MudNavLink>
                }
            </MudNavGroup>
        }
</MudNavMenu>


@code {
    private List<string> _menuList = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
        {
            _menuList.Add($"Menu Item {i}");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually i am not missing them i will place them inside  Group i am not able to loop that group if possible can u help me with an example looping through `MudNavGroup`

Comment: Modified my answer.